# Hash a password but still simply use Eloquents ::create($input)

Tags: php, security, laravel, hash, eloquent

Using Laravel 4.2 for a user system and working on registration.

After my validation passes I do this:

```
User::create($input);
return Redirect::to('/');
```

Which correctly stores my user, but it has an un-hashed password of course since its just passing in:

```
$Input = Input::all();
```

I don't want to manually be adding all the fields into the create method, is there a way to still pass in just $input, but hash the password part?

Also should I be using hash or encrypt on Laravel for passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add all the fields. One option could be to retrieve only password field from the input array and replace it by the hashed password.

```
$input = \Input::all();
// get the password and save it with its hash
$input['password'] = \Hash::make($input['password']);
User::create($input);
return Redirect::to('/');
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `Eloquent` model, so you can easily convert the password attribute through model itself.

Just add this function to your `Eloquent` model and just do whatever you are doing, no need to change the `$input` array.

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($password);
}
```

This way you can apply any type of modifications on your request data attributes.